# Como criar funcao para view?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2

Estou criando uma função no `controller UsersController`, esta função é para usuários que esquecem a senha. Quando tento abrir a `view`, retorna um erro que a função não existe.

A estrutura está assim:

- view `esqueci_senha.ctp`
- função `function esqueciSenha()`

Para abrir a view faço assim:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->Html->url("/Users/esqueci_senha")?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i> Esqueci minha senha</a>`
```

O erro:

> Error: The action esqueci_senha is not defined in controller
>   UsersController
>
> Error: Create UsersController::esqueci_senha() in file:
>   app\Controller\UsersController.php.
>
> class UsersController extends AppController {
>
> public function esqueci_senha() {
>
> }
>
> }

Como resolver?

Answer (score 1):

O erro diz que ele está esperando que a *action*, no seu *controller*, chame `esqueci_senha`, e não `esqueciSenha`. Acho que basta corrigir isso no controller:

```
function esqueci_senha() {
    // código da action
}
```

Comment: eu ja havia feito isto, troquei o nome da funcao como vc esta sugerindo e tbm o nome da view, mas quando clico no link para abrir simplesmente não abre, recarrega a página e não abre.

Comment: E com o URL `/Users/esqueciSenha`?

Comment: Ai da o seguinte erro: `Error: The view for UsersController::esqueciSenha() was not found.`

Comment: consegui resolver, a funcao tem q se chamar `esqueciSenha` e a view `esqueci_senha`, fiz isso e funcionou. obrigado.

Comment: Ué, mas era isso que você dizia que tinha e não funcionava!

Comment: nao, olha no post que na url eu invocava a view `esqueci_senha` e agora mudei pra invocar a funcao `esqueciSenha`, acho que por padrao o cake usa o underline para a view quando a funcao eh camelcase.

Answer (score 0):

Na Controller:

```
Class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function esqueciSenha() {

    }

}
```

Nome do arquivo: esqueci_senha.php